# Generating a sequence based on a field

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table (9.3) which has a field called a.locations. I want to generate a temp table with a sequence for the same, but with similar locations having the same sequence number. To make things clearer, my current table(Example Only):

```
ID        |        Locations
 1        |        Bangalore
 2        |        New York
 3        |        London
 4        |        Bangalore
 5        |        New York
```

What i need is:

```
 ID       |        Locations
 1        |        Bangalore
 1        |        Bangalore
 2        |        London
 3        |        New York
 3        |        New York
```

Appreciate any help whatsoever. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO #temp (ID, locations)
SELECT l2.minID, l1.locations
FROM location l1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT locations, MIN(ID) AS minID
    FROM location
    GROUP BY locations
) l2
    ON l1.locations = l2.locations
```

Comment: Thanks for this...What if i want to generate a new sequence?.. As i mentioned i want to create a temp table and not update the original one...